# Evento de ventana, cuando no se hace click en un div desaparecer (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Cada que se hace clic en un botón aparece un `<div id="fondonegro">` el cual contiene información tipo menú. Cuando no se haga clic en `<div id="fondonegro">` que haga un `display:none` con Javascript.

Es un botón duplicado, el 1er boton tiene como `id="1"` y el segundo `id="2"`. Cuando se haga clic en `id="1"` hace la función `menu()`, y si se hace clic en `id="2"` hace menu1()

Quisiera que cuando no se haga clic en `<div id="fondonegro">` desaparezca.

```
function menu() {
    document.getElementById("fondonegro").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("2").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("1").style.display='none';
    drop();
}
function menu1(){
    document.getElementById("fondonegro").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("2").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("1").style.display='block';
}

function drop(){
    window.onclick = function(event) {
          if (!event.target.matches('#fondonegro')) {
             menu1();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tomado de esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element) de stackoverfow en ingles, lo que hace escuchar el evento click en todo el *document* para ocultar el componente DOM en tu caso #fondonegro pero para que no se oculte el elemento cuando haces click en el mismo elemento, debe verificar si este no esta en el chain de componentes que originaron el evento onClick usando closest.

```
$(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('#fondonegro').length) {
        if($('#fondonegro').is(":visible")) {
            $('#fondonegro').hide();
        }
    }        
})
```

Ojo que utiliza jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente añade un handler para el evento `click` en `document` y mira si el objetivo de dicho evento es `#fondonegro` o sus hijos.

**Ejemplo**

```js
let back = document.getElementById('fondonegro');
let open = document.getElementById('open');


open.addEventListener('click', function() {
  back.style.display = 'inline-block';
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let target = e.target;
  let children = [].map.call(back.children, (c) => c);

  if (target === open) {
    return;
  }

  if (target !== back && !children.includes(target)) {
    back.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```css
#fondonegro {
  background-color: #000;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 25px;
}

#fondonegro #hijo {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button id="open">Abrir</button>
<br />
<div id="fondonegro">
  <div id="hijo">
    Soy un hijo de #fondonegro
  </div>
</div>
```

Si `#fondonegro` tiene hijos que deben ser clickables, entonces, es necesario verificiar que, además de que la fuente del click no fue `#fondonegro` tampoco lo sean sus hijos. Esto se logra en la condición:

```
(target !== back && !children.includes(target))
```

De esta manera te aseguras que desaparezca solo si no se ha hecho click fuera del elemento.

---

**Nota**: El código presente usa características de ES6 como `Array#includes`. Si se desea usar ES5 debes reemplazarlo por `children.indexOf(target) === -1`.